# Evenly space children of Group

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

With this simple example of 3 buttons, how can I have the buttons spaced evenly.

```
<s:HGroup width="100%">
    <s:Button label="button 1" />
    <s:Button label="button 2" />
    <s:Button label="button 3" />
</s:HGroup>
```

It currently appears as:

[image: Current]

I would like it something like:

[image: After]

Comment: align button1 left, button2 center, button3 right.

Comment: @Shark: But what if I have 4 buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put spacer elements between the Buttons and set their widths to 100% so that they take up all the available space.

You can use the old mx [Spacer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Spacer.html) for the job:

```
<s:HGroup width="100%">
    <s:Button label="button 1" />
    <mx:Spacer width="100%"/>
    <s:Button label="button 2" />
    <mx:Spacer width="100%"/>
    <s:Button label="button 3" />
</s:HGroup>
```

but if you'd like to avoid mx classes then use the most lightweight Spark class that implements `IVisualElement`. To my knowledge that would be [GraphicElement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/supportClasses/GraphicElement.html).

```
<s:HGroup width="100%">
    <s:Button label="button 1" />
    <s:GraphicElement width="100%"/>
    <s:Button label="button 2" />
    <s:GraphicElement width="100%"/>
    <s:Button label="button 3" />
</s:HGroup>
```

Spacer extends UIComponent and as such it is heavier than GraphicElement.